# CString.Format crashes in 32-bit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CString format which causes a crash in 32-bit Unicode MFC Static/VS2013 project in SDK file output.c line 1629 `while (i-- && *pwch)`

```
bool MyClass::Function1(LPCTSTR sAppName, HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR tcszValue1, LPCTSTR tcszValue2, LPCTSTR tcszValue3, BOOL bValue)
{     
    __int64 nAppId=0;
    __int64 nId2=0;
    sSql.Format(_T("INSERT INTO Table (AppId, Id2, RegPath, RegKey, RegValueName, 
         bRecurseDelete, RemoveIt) VALUES ('%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', 1)"), 
         nAppId, nId2, tcszValue1, tcszValue2, tcszValue3, bValue);
}
```

When I compile it in 64-bit it works without any problem, in 32-bit it crashes when sValue3 is empty (but not the first time, on the 4th call to CString.Format when sValue is empty)

Comment: It should not crash, what are the actual values of  tcszValue1, tcszValue2, tcszValue3,  bValue? Try to simplyfy the format string and look when it stops crashing, that might give you a clue.

Comment: The last sentence of your question needs editing. What is sValue ? and sValue3 ?

Comment: sValue is L"SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID" , sValue2=L"{0227cf80-1f01-11d6-a4e5-00e02921ea26}" and sValue3=L""

Comment: OK now it's clear, see my answer below. And now you understand that all details are important when you ask a question. Before your edits, nobody could guess that `nAppId` and `nId2` are `__int64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the `%lld` format specifier instead of the `%d` specifier.

In the 32 bit world, `%d` expects a 32 bit integer. But you provide 64 bit integers as arguments. Therefore you get undefined behaviour because `Format` will completly mix up the arguments.

Comment: Thanks!! That was the problem!, but can I use the %lld when I compile it in 64-bit?

Comment: @MarioM actually you _should_ use `%lld`, on the 64 version `%d` works by chance.

Comment: I have tried before with %64d but again it worked only in 64-bit exe, not in 32bit

Comment: Isn't it `%I64d` rather than `%64d` ?

Comment: `%64d` is like `%d`, the "64" meaning that the output for this format specifier will be padded with spaces to 64 characters. So it's normal that `%64d` results in a crash in the 32 bit version.

Comment: So then I should use `%I64d` or `%lld` in order to make it work in both 32-bit and 64-bit ?

Comment: @MarioM yes, exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Bad! You are not allowed to use a CString object in a Format statement. Always use GetString!

```
CString sValue1 = tcszValue1;
CString sValue2 = tcszValue2;
CString sValue3 = tcszValue3;

sSql.Format(_T("INSERT INTO Table (AppId, Id2, RegPath, RegKey, RegValueName, bRecurseDelete, RemoveIt) VALUES ('%d', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', 1)"), 
    nAppId, nId2, sValue1.GetString(), sValue2.GetString(), sValue3.GetString(), bValue);
```

Comment: first I had the tcszValue which is a LPCTSTR parameter for the function, then I have changed to CString, but it still crashed

Comment: Ok, I have tried with GetString() but it still crashes.

Comment: Yes and No, you are right you should not use a  CString object in a Format statement, but CString has been designed in such a way that it works,

Comment: I have simplified the question